# subset a dataframe after a for loop and manipulate

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to write a for loop where I can subset a dataframe for each unique ID and create a new column.  In my example, I want to create a new balance based on the ID, balance and initial amount.  My idea was to loop through each group of ID's, take that subset and follow it up with some if/if else statements.  In the iteration I want the loop to look at all of the unique ID's, for example when I loop though df["ID"] == 2, there should be 7 rows, since their balances are all related to each other.  This is what my dataframe would look like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"ID" : [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,4,4,4],
     "Initial amount": 
    [3250,10800,6750,12060,8040,4810,12200,13000,10700,12000,27000], 
    "Balance": [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2617,19250,19250,19250], "expected output": 
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2617,10720,8530,0]})
```

My current code looks like this, but I feel like i'm headed towards the wrong direction.  Thanks!

```
unique_ids = list(df["ID"].unique())
new_output = []
for i in range(len(unique_ids)):
    this_id = unique_ids[i]
    subset = df.loc[df["ID"] == this_id,:] 
for j in range(len(subset)):
this_bal = subset["Balance"]
this_amt = subset["Initial amount"]
if j == 0:
    this_output = np.where(this_bal >= this_amt, this_amt, this_bal)
    new_output.append(this_output)
elif this_bal - sum(this_output) >= this_amt:
    this_output = this_amt
    new_output.append(this_output)
else:
    this_output = this_bal - sum(this_output)
    new_output.append(this_output)
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It isn't possible to give you a good answer unless we know what these if-else statements are doing. Please provide your expected output.

Comment: Hey, I just edited it, thanks so much @coldspeed

Comment: You are using a `for` loop on integers, the 1st line in 3rd block of code should be `for j in range(len(subset)):` and also you are using `output.append`, where `output` is not defined. Could you edit your code further

Comment: @Sumanth Hey, I know there are mistakes, The 2nd and 3rd block should be together, but I don't how to move foward.